# Advance VBA and SQL Code not matching catagorys

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am reaching out because in my code I want to match a few categories with what is in the current open Access form referring to this table "tbl_PgmAndReqMonthly_Input". I want to match the following categories with the table called "Unit Program". (Basically, filtering the following fields)

[Parent Organization]
[Functional Area]
[Fund]
[Funding Category]

Once they are matched and filtered, I want to get the total of the field [unit funding]
Then I want to show that number in the form in the text box labeled txtPgmTotal.

Then I want to display TotalPgm number in the txtPgmUsed.

Then I wish to subtract the text box in the form labeled txtPgmRemaining out of it

[Unit Funding] – [Total Program]

However, my code simply shows me this error (Image below).

Where have I gone wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En5vl.png)

Code Below

```vb
    Private Sub programInput()
    
        Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
        Dim strSQL As String
        
    
        strSQL = "SELECT SUM([Unit Program]) AS Limit FROM [Unit Funding] WHERE [Parent Organization] = """ & Me.ParentOrg & _
                                                                        """ And [Functional Area] = """ & Me.FunctionalArea & _
                                                                        """ And [Fund] = """ & Me.Fund & _
                                                                        """ And [Funding Category] = """ & Me.FundingCategory """
                                                                        
        Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        
        If IsNull(rst!Limit) Then
        
            programSQL = 0
            Me.txtPgmTotal.Value = 0
            
        Else
        
            programSQL = rst!Limit
            Me.txtPgmTotal.Value = programSQL
              
        End If
          
        totalAdj = 0
            
        'PgmOnly + From
        'strSQL = "SELECT SUM(TotalPgm) AS Adjusted FROM tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input WHERE ParentOrg = """ & Me.ParentOrg & """ And FunctionalArea = """ & Me.FunctionalArea & """" _
        '& " And RID <> """ & Me.Text348.Value & """ And Fund = """ & Me.Fund & """ And [FundingCategory] = """ & Me.FundingCategory & """"
        Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        
        If Not IsNull(rst!Adjusted) Then totalAdj = totalAdj + rst!Adjusted
        
        'PgmReq + From
       strSQL = "SELECT SUM(TotalPgm) AS Adjusted FROM tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input WHERE ParentOrg = """ & Me.ParentOrg & """ And FunctionalArea = """ & Me.FunctionalArea & """" _
    & " And RID <> """ & Me.Text348.Value & """ And Fund = """ & Me.Fund & """ And [FundingCategory] = """ & Me.FundingCategory & """"
        
        Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        
        If Not IsNull(rst!Adjusted) Then totalAdj = totalAdj + rst!Adjusted
        
        Me.txtPgmUsed.Value = totalAdj
        Me.txtPgmRemaining.Value = programSQL - totalAdj
        
    End Sub
    
    Function programCheck() As Integer
    
        Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
        Dim strSQL As String
    
        If Me.TotalPgm.Value <= 0 Then
        
            programCheck = 1
            Exit Function
            
        End If
    
    
    
        strSQL = "SELECT SUM([Unit Program]) AS Limit FROM [Unit Funding] WHERE [Parent Organization] = """ & Me.ParentOrg & _
                                                                        """ And [Functional Area] = """ & Me.FunctionalArea & _
                                                                        """ And [Fund] = """ & Me.Fund & _
                                                                        """ And [Funding Category] = """ & Me.FundingCategory & """
                                                                       
    
        Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        
        If IsNull(rst!Limit) Then
        
            programCheck = -1
            
        Else
            programSQL = rst!Limit
                
            totalAdj = 0
                
            'PgmReq + From
    
            strSQL = "SELECT SUM(TotalPgm) AS Adjusted FROM tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input WHERE ParentOrg = """ & Me.ParentOrg & """ And FunctionalArea = """ & Me.FunctionalArea & """" _
            & " And RID <> """ & Me.Text348.Value & """ And Fund = """ & Me.Fund & """ And [FundingCategory] = """ & Me.FundingCategory & """"
            
            Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
            If Not IsNull(rst!Adjusted) Then totalAdj = totalAdj + rst!Adjusted
            
            'PgmandReq + From
            strSQL = "SELECT SUM(TotalPgm) AS Adjusted FROM tbl_PgmAndReqMonthly_Input WHERE ParentOrg = """ & Me.ParentOrg & """ And FunctionalArea = """ & Me.FunctionalArea & """" _
            & " And RID <> """ & Me.Text348.Value & """ And Fund = """ & Me.Fund & """ And [FundingCategory] = """ & Me.FundingCategory & """"
            
            Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
            If Not IsNull(rst!Adjusted) Then totalAdj = totalAdj + rst!Adjusted
            
            totalAdj = totalAdj + Me.TotalPgm.Value
            
            If programSQL >= totalAdj Then
            
                programCheck = 1
            
            Else
            
                programCheck = 0
            
            End If
            
        End If
        
        rst.Close
        Set rst = Nothing
    
    End Function
```

Comment: I can't view that link at work and I'm not sure what an image would add to your question.  Your code is vulnerable to SQL Code Injection attack - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "to call Contract Name". The contract name is used for filtering. Don't you want to filter by it anymore?

Comment: Your code cannot raise that error, but the form can. So, something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Just go through and remove all the references to ContractName making sure that you don't remove unrelated text e.g. the first part could become

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT SUM([Unit Program]) AS Limit FROM [Unit Funding] WHERE [Parent Organization] = """ & Me.ParentOrg & _
                                                                """ And [Functional Area] = """ & Me.FunctionalArea & _
                                                                """ And [Fund] = """ & Me.Fund & _
                                                                """ And [Funding Category] = """ & Me.FundingCategory "";" 

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Note the `"""` that was in front of ContractName in that example is still required.
Although your code would be a lot clearer if you used the single-quotation mark - or better yet Parameterised Queries

It gets messier further down because of the string concatenation but still just a case of removing references to that column e.g.

```
strSQL = "SELECT SUM(TotalPgm) AS Adjusted FROM tbl_ProgramMonthly_Input WHERE ParentOrg = """ & Me.ParentOrg & """ And FunctionalArea = """ & Me.FunctionalArea & """" _
& " And RID <> """ & Me.Text348.Value & """ And Fund = """ & Me.Fund & """ And [FundingCategory] = """ & Me.FundingCategory & """
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that simply gives me a Thier are no records to navigate to.